# How to access the current IWorld Instance of the Overworld from a seperate class

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm currently trying to modify a Specific Block's BlockState (at a known position) from a seperate thread which is watching and waiting for external events to occur (not Minecraft related). To do this I would be required to get the overworld World Instance and call the `setBlockState` method of the IWorld class. Since this seperate thread isn't passed any Server or World parameters, I need to somehow get the instance manually (possibly from a `public static` variable or a getter method)

Is there a simple way to get an IWorld instance of the current Overworld from a class (An alternative to the unavailable MinecraftServer.getServer() method)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By following the usages, implementations, and hierarchies of the `MinecraftServer` parameter, I discovered the `ServerLifecycleHooks` class with the following declaration `private static MinecraftServer currentServer` which contains a reference to the current running `MinecraftServer` instance. This variable has a getter method which can be called through `ServerLifecycleHooks.getCurrentServer()`.

You can then store the server instance or immediately call the `getWorld(DimensionType dimension)` method on it to get a reference of any of the Worlds. This function returns a `MinecraftServer` type which extends the `IWorld` type and can be used as you needed. An example implementation would be as follows to get the Overworld, Nether and End worlds respectively:

```
MinecraftServer currentServer = ServerLifecycleHooks.getCurrentServer();

IWorld currentOverworld = currentServer.getWorld(DimensionType.OVERWORLD);
IWorld currentNether = currentServer.getWorld(DimensionType.THE_NETHER);
IWorld currentEnd = currentServer.getWorld(DimensionType.THE_END);
```